# Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object while trying to access object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am trying to access array inside object using `Object.keys(obj.arr));` method. If I access array directly like below, then it is giving proper output:

```
 alert(Object.keys(obj.arr));
```

but if I pass array name using parameter then it is giving error :

```
var selected = "arr";
alert(Object.keys(obj.arr));

error : Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
```

There is example : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv6TY/6/)**

Comment: Both of your snippets do the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need dynamic property access, you cannot use `.value`. That is always literally accessing named key of  `"value"`. If you want to access property with the key name contained in the variable `value` you need to use brackets: `obj[value]`

Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv6TY/7/

```
console.log("Variable Pass "+Object.keys(groups[selected]));
```