# puzzling Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
if(typeof x == 'object')
    return "{"+Object.keys(x)+"}";
```

It results in (Chrome):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
```

Can anybody tell me what's going on here? Btw: Firefox does the same.

ps: Don't know what the object is. Firefox debugging failed me.

Comment: Perhaps the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319336/uncaught-typeerror-object-keys-called-on-non-object-while-trying-to-access-obje

Comment: What's `x`? Maybe it's `null`?

Comment: Is `x` null? typeof will return `object` for a null value

Comment: @JanDvorak: That's probably it.  `type null` is `"object"`, and would cause this exact error :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x` is most likely `null` (which is an object).  You should explicitly check with `if(typeof x === 'object' && x !== null)`

Walking through the spec (to explain the logic):

`Object.keys`: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14 reads

> If the Type(O) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.

This `Type` is `Null` for `null` (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.2)

`typeof`: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3

The table shows that the `typeof null` is in fact `"object"`

So in fact `null` satisfies `typeof x === "object"` and triggers a `TypeError` exception